# Problem with starting minecraft server from php

Tags: php, server, minecraft, ssh2

```
<?php
$serverAddress = 'ip';       // Replace with the IP address of your remote server
$sshUsername = 'root';      // Replace with your SSH username
$sshPassword = 'pass';      // Replace with your SSH password
$minecraftDir = 'path';

// Connect to the remote server via SSH
$connection = ssh2_connect($serverAddress, 22);

if (!$connection) {
    die("SSH connection failed.");
}

// Authenticate with the SSH credentials
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $sshUsername, $sshPassword)) {
    die("SSH authentication failed.");
}

// Open a shell
$shell = ssh2_shell($connection, 'xterm');

if (!$shell) {
    die("Failed to open shell.");
}

// Check if the Minecraft server is online
fwrite($shell, "pgrep -a java | grep serwer.jar\n");
sleep(1);
$output = stream_get_contents($shell);

if (strpos($output, "serwer.jar") !== false) {
    echo "Minecraft server is online." . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Minecraft server is offline. Starting it..." . PHP_EOL;
    
    // Start the Minecraft server
    fwrite($shell, "cd $minecraftDir && screen java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar serwer.jar nogui");
    sleep(5); // Wait for the server to start
    
    // Check again if the server is online
    fwrite($shell, "pgrep -a java | grep serwer.jar\n");
    sleep(1);
    $output = stream_get_contents($shell);
    
    if (strpos($output, "serwer.jar") !== false) {
        echo "Minecraft server has been started." . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Failed to start Minecraft server." . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Close the SSH connection and shell
fclose($shell);
fclose($connection);
?>
```

`root@ip13:~# screen -r There is no screen to be resumed. root@ip13:~#`

I have problem with ssh2 because it says that the server is online but neither my terminal or Minecraft server is not online and I dont know how to fix it.

I need that code to be able to start a server and be visible in terminal so i can execute server commands from terminal,

Comment: You should precise the name of the screen after "-r" option

Comment: @Elikill58 but if it would started it would be visible there no matter if there is name or not. the problem is that is not even starting the server